# How can I get Eclipse PDT to only show my code templates on CTRL-SPACEBAR?

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

In an earlier version of Eclipse PDT, when I typed e.g. "sh" and pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>SPACEBAR</kbd>, it showed me only my code templates which started with "sh".

In the newest version I downloaded, it seems to be showing me every single method in every class which begins with "sh" which is too much.

**How can I get Eclipse PDT to just show me only my code templates when pressing CTRL-SPACEBAR?**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the same solution is used in PDT, but the JDT has a setting in Preferences/Java/Editor/Content Assist/Advanced, where it is possible to change the proposal kinds. It might be worth checking whether something similar exists for PDT (I don't have one installed right now).

Comment: thanks, but in pdt there are a lot of options there, but non of them seem to turn off the flood of suggestions it gives.